# How can i stop Listview repeating the titles?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

**Hello im new in coding and i´m creating an app and need a little help from you guys!**

My First row of the table view is repeating always when i have data to show.

This is the output of my app:

[image]

I want it to be like a normal table like this:

[image]

Im gonna show you my code:

My "main activity":

```
public class Administracao extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String[] MATRICULA = new String[]{
            "10-NX-68", "21-30-XJ", "54-HI-11", "90-29-VE"
    };

    private AutoCompleteTextView editText_Matric;

    //Referencias base de dados
    DatabaseReference reff2;

    private FirebaseDatabase database;

    Spinner spinner;

     String selected_item;



     //Testes Firebase listview apagar se der erro


    List<Dados_Administracao> administracao_adapter;
    ListView listViewCondutores;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_administracao);

        editText_Matric = findViewById(R.id.actv);
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_seguinte);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MATRICULA);
        editText_Matric.setAdapter(adapter);

        //TESTES FIREBASE list view
        listViewCondutores = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        administracao_adapter = new ArrayList<>();


        editText_Matric.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                //Mostrar todos os registos

                reff2 = database.getInstance().getReference().child("Registo Inicial e Final");

                reff2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        administracao_adapter.clear();


                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                             Dados_Administracao dt = ds.getValue(Dados_Administracao.class);


                            if(ds.child("matricula").getValue().equals(editText_Matric.getText().toString())) {

                                administracao_adapter.add(dt);

                            }


                          }

                        Administracao_adapter adapter2 = new Administracao_adapter(Administracao.this, administracao_adapter);

                        listViewCondutores.setAdapter(adapter2);

                      //  adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();



                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        // Handle possible errors.
                        Log.e("The read failed: " ,databaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }


        });

    }
```

The Activity where i store the data:

```
 public class Dados_Administracao {

       private String observacoes,matricula,datainicio,horainicio,datafim,horafim,nomecondutor,marca,codprojeto,latfinal,longfinal,obsfinal,latitude,longitude,kminicial,kmfinal;


        public Dados_Administracao(){

        }

        public Dados_Administracao(String observacoes, String matricula, String datainicio, String horainicio, String datafim, String horafim, String nomecondutor, String marca, String codprojeto, String latfinal, String longfinal, String obsfinal, String latitude, String longitude, String kminicial, String kmfinal) {
            this.observacoes = observacoes;
            this.matricula = matricula;
            this.datainicio = datainicio;
            this.horainicio = horainicio;
            this.datafim = datafim;
            this.horafim = horafim;
            this.nomecondutor = nomecondutor;
            this.marca = marca;
            this.codprojeto = codprojeto;
            this.latfinal = latfinal;
            this.longfinal = longfinal;
            this.obsfinal = obsfinal;
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
            this.kminicial = kminicial;
            this.kmfinal = kmfinal;
        }

        public String getObservacoes() {
            return observacoes;
        }

        public String getMatricula() {
            return matricula;
        }

        public String getDatainicio() {
            return datainicio;
        }

        public String getHorainicio() {
            return horainicio;
        }

        public String getDatafim() {
            return datafim;
        }

        public String getHorafim() {
            return horafim;
        }

        public String getNomecondutor() {
            return nomecondutor;
        }

        public String getMarca() {
            return marca;
        }

        public String getCodprojeto() {
            return codprojeto;
        }

        public String getLatfinal() {
            return latfinal;
        }

        public String getLongfinal() {
            return longfinal;
        }

        public String getObsfinal() {
            return obsfinal;
        }

        public String getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public String getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public String getKminicial() {
            return kminicial;
        }

        public String getKmfinal() {
            return kmfinal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should debug the app and learn what is hold in `adapter`, `adapter2` and `administracao_adapter`. If you obtain what you expect, there maybe a problem in setting adapter or refreshing `ListView`. I usually used `ViewHolder`s. In `Dados_Administracao dados = adminnistracao_Adapter.get(position);` you get data, see, what's inside.

Comment: Your `Adapter_view_layout` should contain only those things that you want to appear in every single row. The header should be handled separately – e.g., by adding a header to the `ListView` directly, or just handling it manually in the `Adapter` – so it should basically be just a row of `TextView`s.

Comment: Thanks man, i did it Mike and it worked fine ;)). Just one question, do you know how i can put the scroll view working simultaneously ??

Answer (score 2):

If you're set on using a `ListView` then it directly supports adding headers to your list, have a look at [**addHeaderView(View v)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView#addHeaderView(android.view.View)).

So what you would do in this case is separate the header part from your row layout into a new layout file, inflate it and call `listViewCondutores.addHeaderView(inflatedView)`.

However a [**`RecyclerView`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)  might better suit your needs here and is generally recommended over `ListView`. Then even though this doesn't directly support header views, it supports multiple view types!

Comment: Hello man, thanks for your help. Do you know how to make all the rows of the table scrolling at the same time ?? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I am not quite sure I understand your question, how are they scrolling at the moment if not at the same time?

Comment: I make a video with the problem, you can see here:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6YjiAw-a8Q&list=UUsd3qFXsTE8rXHGUf6DBT_Q

Comment: Although not an ideal solution, I would recommend wrapping your ```ListView```/```RecyclerView``` in a ```HorizontalScrollView``` instead of having any scroll views inside your adapter row layout!

Comment: And just to clarify, you don't need either the```ScrollView``` or the ```HorizontalScrollView``` in ```adapter_view_layout.xml```. The ```ListView```/```RecyclerView``` handles vertical scrolling!

Comment: I erase the scroll views from the adapter view layout, and i put the scrollview on listview layout and now all the rows are scrolling at the same time :). But the titles of the table stil not scrolling with the rows.. If i put the same scroll view on the title and listview, the app crashes ://

Comment: Oh really? I have made some test code and it works fine for me! Are you using ```addHeaderView``` like in my solution?

Comment: Yes, should i use addHeaderView how does it works??

Comment: Have a look at the documentation I have linked in my answer! If you need any more help, let me know.

Comment: Do i need to inflate the textfields from the titles in my class "Administracao_adapter" or do i need a new class ??

Comment: I just used this code and work fine :  ViewGroup headerView = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.teste_layout,listViewCondutores,false);

        listViewCondutores.addHeaderView(headerView);